# Java - bit shifting with integers and bytes

Tags: java, int, byte, bit-shift

Consider the following code (where byteIndex is an int):

```
int bitNumber = b-(8*byteIndex);
bitMask = 0x8>>(byte)bitNumber;
```

This generates the error

```
error: possible loss of precision
```

when compiled (required byte, found int).

The code

```
int bitNumber = b-(8*byteIndex);
bitMask = 0x8>>2;
```

compiles fine.

What is the problem here and how do I fix the first example to allow bit shifting by the int value?

EDIT: Following the comments, here is a more-complete example:

```
48) int byteIndex;
49) byte bitMask;
50) int bitNumber;
    // assign value to byteIndex
67) bitNumber = b-(8*byteIndex);
68) bitMask = 0x8>>bitNumber;
```

and the error given is:

```
...MyClass.java:68: error: possible loss of precision
    bitMask = 0x8>>bitNumber;
             ^
  required: byte
  found:    int
1 error
```

Comment: Real java errors have line numbers.

Comment: What is the type of `bitMask`?? And the type of `b` too??

Comment: If they are of type `int`, then on my compiler, both codes are working fine..

Comment: There is no line number 68 in your code ... honestly: it would really help if you provide a complete example, ideally including a main method. As @RohitJain, I am not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @GregS: If it's that important, I've added the line number, but I don't see how it makes the question any more general and helps others who might have this problem? Or indeed how it helps people answer this specific question?

Comment: I should add, bitMask is a byte - and needs to stay this way.

Comment: Yes you should add that, to the question :p

Comment: If people can't reproduce it, then it's something else that's getting in the way. Locate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert your `shifting` line to this:  -

```
byte bitMask = (byte)(0x8>>(byte)bitNumber);
```

Your RHS, is an int, you need to typecast it to byte..

Above code will work fine.. With or without the `casting` of `bitNumber` to `byte`

So, you can also have : -

```
byte bitMask = (byte)(0x8>>bitNumber);
```

But, here's is a question - `byte bitMask = 0x8>>3;` works fine.. Why is it so??

**Here's some example to explain the reason behind its working and also the behaviour with `final`: -**

```
byte bitMask;
int varInt1 = 3;
final int finalVarInt2 = 3;
final int finalVarInt3 = 4;

bitMask = 0x8>>varInt1;    // 1. Will not work. 
bitMask = 0x8<<3;          // 2. Will work

bitMask = 0x8<<4;          // 3. Will not work
bitMask = 0x8<<finalVarInt2;   // 1. Will work
bitMask = 0x8<<finalVarInt3;   // 2. Will not work
```

**Here's some reasoning that explains the above behaviour: -**

- The value on the RHS will be `typecasted` implicitly only if, the compiler is sure that, it will be able to accomodate that value in the `byte` variable on LHS.. Else, we have to do `Explicit type casting` to tell compiler that, we know what we are doing, just do it for us..

*Now lets consider all the cases one-by-one (From the above code (1-3, 1-2):  -*

1. **`varInt1`** initially contains **3**. So the value of **RHS** evaluates to **64**. Although this value might get accomodated to **`byte`** variable in **LHS**, but compiler also knows that, it is possible to change the value of **`varInt1`**.. So what if value of **`varInt1`** is changed to **4** at some stage.. It won't work then.. That's why it is not allowed..
2. Now, in this case, since we have explicitly used an **`Integer Literal`** here, so compiler is sure that it will accomodate in **`byte`**.. So it allows the **`implicit`** casting..
3. Again, in this case, it is known that **`RHS`** will evaluate to **`128`** which can't be accomodated in **`byte`**.. *Failed again*..

**Last two cases** are different from regular variables... Since they are declared **`final`**, they can't be re-initialized.. So, compiler can make a decision based on the assigned value..

1. In this case, compiler sees that, **`finalVarInt2`** contains value **3**. So, **RHS** evaluates to **64**, which can be accommodated in the **`byte`** variable on **LHS**. Now, since the variable is **`final`** it can't be changed, and `Compiler` knows that, so it is sure that t**his value will always be `64`**.. So compiler allows this.
2. In the last case, value of **`finalVarInt3`** is 4.. Similar reasoning.. Won't fit in **LHS**, as **RHS** evaluates to **128** which can't fit into **`byte`**

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, bitnumber is an int (32 bits), and when you cast it as a byte (8 bits), you are losing the high order 24 bits. Therefore you are losing precision. Just leave the cast (byte) off.

Comment: I've omitted the cast, but am still getting exactly the same error? bitMask is a byte, I should have stated this before.

Comment: java -version prints:
java version "1.7.0_06-icedtea"

Comment: "0x8" is an integer by default, afaik. Just keeping the "outer" cast should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is not the answer, the correct answer is the one Rohit Jain wrote, but this is first time I saw such behavior of JVM, compare these codes:

version where `bitNumber` is marked as **final**

```java
final int bitNumber = 10;
final byte bitMask = 0x8 >> bitNumber;
```

version where `bitNumber` is not final

```java
int bitNumber = 10;
bitNumber = 10;
final byte bitMask = 0x8 >> bitNumber;
```

And there is error is second example, probably some optimization. It would be great if someone knows the reason ;-)