# Interesting behaviour return values of bitwise operators and bit shift in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

So I came over a weird behaviour regarding bitwise operators and bit shift. I was trying to make a small check faster by using bit masks and I came accross this:

```
public class Weirdness {

    private final static int constant = 3;

    private static int notConstant = 3;

    public void stuff() {
        byte a = 0b1 << 3;
        byte b = 0b1 << (int) 3;
        byte c = 0b1 << constant;
        byte d = 0b1 << notConstant; //error
        byte e = 0b1 << getAnInt(); //error
        byte f = 0b1 << getAFinalInt(); //error
        int i = 3;
        byte g = 0b1 << i; //error
        final int j = 3;
        byte h = 0b1 << j;
    }

    public static int getAnInt() {
        return 3;
    }

    public static final int getAFinalInt() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

`a`, `b`, `c` and `h` do not give compilation errors; But `d`, `e`, `f` and `g` do. The compiler asks to cast explicitly to `byte` or to declare the last variables as `int`. I have noticed a similar behaviour with the bitwize `&` and `|` too.

Could someone explain what is happening here?
What kind of magic is compiler working for the `a`, `b`, `c` and `h`to work?

**EDIT: Or How this is not exactly a duplicate**

I believe this question is different because from [Why can not I add two bytes and get an int and I can add two final bytes get a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100019/why-can-not-i-add-two-bytes-and-get-an-int-and-i-can-add-two-final-bytes-get-a-b) because what is causing the interesting behaviour is how the compiler optimize the bitwize shift operations.

And since I seek a theoretical answer (because I already understand that I can make my code compile by casting) to how the shift and other bitwize operations determine their return value, I believe this question can complement [Java - bit shifting with integers and bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639471/java-bit-shifting-with-integers-and-bytes) and bring more interesting information to StackOverflow.

Comment: The answer from [Rohit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12639659/180100) is what you are looking for I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

The compiler knows that a `final` value or a `literal` can not change and can safely implicitly `cast` `constant` and `3` to a `byte` with the given values.

Non-final values can't be reasoned about in this same way.

> Explicit is better than implicit.

*This is one example of why I hate `implicit` anything related to writing programs.*

#### Exercise:

change `constant` or the literal `3` to something that won't fit in a `byte` and see how it complains

Comment: If I am not mistaken Java is all pass by value. So why is it not working for `e` and `f`? Since it is working for `c`. I though Java could walk those kind of references and optimize.

Comment: this has nothing to do with `pass by value` or anything else like that, and Java passes `references` by value. A function can return **anything**, `final` on a function just means it can't be overridden, it says nothing about its return value. [Final Word on Final](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/05/the-final-word-on-final/)

Answer (score 5):

[From JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19): The type of the shift expression is the promoted type of the left-hand operand.

The promoted type of `byte` is `int` - and that's the reason why, in most cases, you have to cast the result as follows:

```
byte e = (byte) (0b1 << getAnInt());
```

So the real question is why, on the first 3 lines, there is no need for casting. Now, that's not accurate either cause if you'll change the line:

```
private final static int constant = 3;
```

to:

```
private final static int constant = 1000;
```

you'll get a compilation error on:

```
byte c = 0b1 << constant;
```

as well.

The shift operation might create an integer number which has bigger value than the byte on the left side of the assignment can hold - which triggers the compile-time error and forces us to cast to byte in order to grab only the least significant 8 bits.

So why in the first 3 lines we didn't need to cast to byte ?
The compiler recognized that we're using a constant (or a final) and thus "knows" that this value cannot be changed later on, so it allows [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) for the assignment to byte - on the left side:

```
byte c = 0b1 << 3;
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! So this is basically the cases where I have no errors are actually the excetions and not the other way around. Great answer.